# Is it possible to have different transition times for each flex element inside a flex container on grow/shrink?

Tags: html, css

I have a group of flex items that grow/shrink on :hover
My problem is that they all take the same time to complete their animations even if I specify that each one have their own transition time.

Is it possible to fix this or I will have to use "display: block" and manually code the sizes of each element?

```html
<flex>
  <div class="item bg1" id="item-0"></div>
  <div class="item bg2" id="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item bg3" id="item-2"></div>
  <div class="item bg4" id="item-3"></div>
  <div class="item bg5" id="item-4"></div>
  <div class="item bg6" id="item-5"></div>
  <div class="item bg7" id="item-6"></div>
</flex>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

flex {
  margin-left: -5vw;
  display: flex;
  width: 110vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
}

.item:hover {
  flex-grow: 3;
  max-width:45vw;
}

.bg1 {
  background: #442C59;
}
.bg2 {
  background: #844270;
}
.bg3 {
  background: #DC9A95;
}
.bg4 {
  background: #BEC976;
}
.bg5 {
  background: #CDCA98;
}
.bg6 {
  background: #B04127;
}
.bg7 {
  background: #6B4A4B;
}
```

```
// ITEM 0
$("#item-0").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css({ transition: 'all 1s' });
  $("#item-1").css({    transition: 'all 1.2s' });
  $("#item-2").css({    transition: 'all 1.4s' });
  $("#item-3").css({    transition: 'all 1.6s' });
  $("#item-4").css({    transition: 'all 1.8s' });
  $("#item-5").css({    transition: 'all 2s' });
  $("#item-6").css({ transition: 'all 2.2s' });
});

// ITEM 1
$("#item-1").mouseover(function(){
  $("#item-0").css({ transition: 'all 1.2s' });
  $(this).css({ transition: 'all 1s' });
  $("#item-2").css({ transition: 'all 1.2s' });
  $("#item-3").css({ transition: 'all 1.4s' });
  $("#item-4").css({ transition: 'all 1.6s' });
  $("#item-5").css({ transition: 'all 1.8s' });
  $("#item-6").css({ transition: 'all 2s' });
});

// ITEM 2
$("#item-2").mouseover(function(){
  $("#item-0").css({ transition: 'all 1.4s' });
  $("#item-1").css({ transition: 'all 1.2s' });
  $(this).css({ transition: 'all 1s' });
  $("#item-3").css({ transition: 'all 1.2s' });
  $("#item-4").css({ transition: 'all 1.4s' });
  $("#item-5").css({ transition: 'all 1.6s' });
  $("#item-6").css({ transition: 'all 1.8s' });
});

// ITEM 3
$("#item-3").mouseover(function(){
  $("#item-0").css({ transition: 'all 1.6s' });
  $("#item-1").css({ transition: 'all 1.4s' });
  $("#item-2").css({ transition: 'all 1.2s' });
  $(this).css({ transition: 'all 1s' });
  $("#item-4").css({ transition: 'all 1.2s' });
  $("#item-5").css({ transition: 'all 1.4s' });
  $("#item-6").css({ transition: 'all 1.6s' });
});

// ITEM 4
$("#item-4").mouseover(function(){
  $("#item-0").css({ transition: 'all 1.8s' });
  $("#item-1").css({ transition: 'all 1.6s' });
  $("#item-2").css({ transition: 'all 1.4s' });
  $("#item-3").css({ transition: 'all 1.2s' });
  $(this).css({ transition: 'all 1s' });
  $("#item-5").css({ transition: 'all 1.2s' });
  $("#item-6").css({ transition: 'all 1.4s' });
});

// ITEM 5
$("#item-5").mouseover(function(){
  $("#item-0").css({ transition: 'all 2s' });
  $("#item-1").css({ transition: 'all 1.8s' });
  $("#item-2").css({ transition: 'all 1.6s' });
  $("#item-3").css({ transition: 'all 1.4s' });
  $("#item-4").css({ transition: 'all 1.2s' });
  $(this).css({ transition: 'all 1s' });
  $("#item-6").css({ transition: 'all 1.2s' });
});

//ITEM 6
$("#item-6").mouseover(function(){
  $("#item-0").css({ transition: 'all 2.2s' });
  $("#item-1").css({ transition: 'all 2s' });
  $("#item-2").css({ transition: 'all 1.8s' });
  $("#item-3").css({ transition: 'all 1.6s' });
  $("#item-4").css({ transition: 'all 1.4s' });
  $("#item-5").css({ transition: 'all 1.2s' });
  $(this).css({ transition: 'all 1s' });
});
```

here's a pen https://codepen.io/mateus-ramos/pen/RwbZKgy

Comment: Great question! Have found that it is an [animatable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) but your Codepen does not respond as you would expect. So it might be hard to see in the animation because the intervals are so small. Try to increase the interval time. See if it helps.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier they still move all in the time of the hovered item, ignoring their own, I wanted to achieve something like this [link](http://haveanicedesign.com.br/nova-home/) but with flexbox if possible, so it's easier to code multiple pages

Comment: the trick here is that you are animating one element so transition on all the other will have no effect. Only the hovered element will control the timing

Comment: @TemaniAfif but other elements are changing their width, there's no way to "catch" that change in a transition?

Comment: they are shrinking as a result of the grow of the hover element. So you have only one transitiion which is the grow of one element pushing the other .. if you see the example your are following you will see that all the element have their own transition by adjustung the  `left` property

Comment: It woulld make no sense to have the element shrinking slowly and the one growing fast. The total width of all the element need to remain the same so they all need to have the same timing

Comment: I understand now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user Temani Afif pointed, what I wanted to achieve is not possible with flex display.
I have switched to block display and "hard coded" each size and position.

Temani Afif commented this (and more in the comments section):

> It woulld make no sense to have the element shrinking slowly and the one growing fast. The total width of all the element need to remain the same so they all need to have the same timing